# Running a script with higher permissions as the user?

Tags: 16.04

I am using Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 and I'd like to know if it is possible to let a user run a script that has(needs) a higher permission level than the user has, and if it is, how it is done.

In general I'd like to have a user that can only start a specific script (which would need administrator permissions to run) and to put the PC into sleep mode (pm-sleep-hybrid).

Is there a way to accomplish the first and maybe even the latter?

Comment: It's better to `sudo crontab -e` and put your command there, at desired time. That's how I put my computer to sleep every night

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CAUTION: The following answer references tools that can do harm to your system.

> "The /etc/sudoers file controls who can run what commands as what users on what machines and can also control special things such as whether you need a password for particular commands. The file is composed of aliases (basically variables) and user specifications (which control who can run what)."  [Sudoers - Community Help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers)

You can alter this file to allow users or groups to run commands as other users. Mistakes in this file can do much harm to a system.

If a script was authorized to be run by the sudoers file and then edited by a non privileged user. The new script could potently run any privileged command. Because of this it is best to allow only exact commands to be added to the sudoers file.

First safely edit the file by running `sudo visudo`

If you wanted to allow bob, a no privileged users, to shutdown the system from the console without a password.

To do this you need to add some cmnd aliases as follows:

```
Cmnd_Alias SHUTDOWN_CMDS = /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot
```

You also need to add a user specification (at the end of the file after the "%admin ALL = (ALL) ALL" line so it takes effect - see above for details):

```
bob ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SHUTDOWN_CMDS
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this ?

```
sudo pm-sleep-hybrid
```

You would only then have to add this user to the sudoers group first.

E.g.

```
sudo vi /etc/group
```

and then append the user id at the end of the line where the user sudo is mentioned:

```
sudo:x:27:my_special_user
```

However this user has to enter his password when invoking the script...

Comment: Don't do it this way! Rather use `sudo adduser <userName> sudo` from an account who already has sudo permissions to add the user to sudoers. Anyway the answer by @J. Starnes seems to fit more with the OPs needs.